# How to select all files in SharePoint Online Folder and Download (more than 100)?

Tags: sharepoint-online, file, download

I am trying to select all files in SharePoint folder (2000 files) however when I click on the circle next to name, it only selects 100. How can I select all 2000 files and download them?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Try downloading folder itself if you want to download all files inside a folder. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Oh okay! Will try shortly and let you know! Thanks Ganesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SolutionA:** Download the entire folder directly

[image]

**SolutionB:** Under the folder, select the "**Toggle selection for all items**" checkbox to select all items/files.

[image]

**SolutionC:** In **IE** browser, switch the library page to **classic mode**. Under the folder, select the "**Select and deselect all items**" checkbox and click on "**Open with Explorer**".

[image]